# pgAdmin4 import/export option greyed out

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

so I recently configured and started using Pgadmin 4, managed to set up my localhost database, and my querys work properly, but for some reason I can't use the import/export dialog when I want to export my data as CSV, as it shows as greyed out. Could anyone help me out please? Image for Reference.

EDIT: The "Download as CSV (F8)" button is not working either.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just right click the table and use Import/Export option.

OR

To make Import/Export option you need to select table then click on Tools => Import/Export

And CSV download button is not working on some platform in current version that's a bug and already reported, It'll be fixed in next release.

Comment: What if I want to export a specific query as csv and not the whole table?

Comment: pgAdmin4 version 1.5 is going to be release next week, so we might expect to get 'Download button' issue fixed in that version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking to export the query results , you need to do copy

```
COPY ([Query]) TO '[File Name]' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Make sure you have created the file and it has all permissions to access